# Wifi P2P app: BroadcastReceiver STATE_CHANGED_ACTION is being triggered continuously

Tags: java, android, wifip2p

I'm trying to create a p2p mobile app using Android. I am following the official docs, [linked here](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct). My problem is at the creating a `BroadcastReceiver` section (the section that begins with the sentence: `Now create a new BroadcastReceiver class that you'll use to listen for changes to the System's Wi-Fi P2P state`.

The `onReceive` method is being triggered continuously with an action of `STATE_CHANGED`.  My application is written such that if a `STATE_CHANGED` action is received in the `onReceive()` method, the wifi should be turned on or off. I have a button that is supposed to trigger this event, but for some reason it's being triggered continuously right when the application starts up -- causing the app to oscillate between turning the wifi on and wifi off.

Below is my MainActivity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOnOff, btnDiscover, btnSend;
    ListView listView;
    TextView read_msg_box, connectionStatus;
    EditText writeMsg;

    //For programmatically turning wifi on and off:
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();

    List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
    String[] deviceNameArray;
    WifiP2pDevice[] deviceArray;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialWork();
        exqListener();
    }

    private void exqListener() {
        btnOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    btnOnOff.setText("ON");
                } else {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    btnOnOff.setText("OFF");
                }
            }
        });

        btnDiscover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Started");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Failed");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialWork() {
        btnOnOff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.onOff);
        btnDiscover = (Button)findViewById(R.id.discover);
        btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.peerListView);
        read_msg_box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readMsg);
        connectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
        writeMsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.writeMsg);

        wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        mManager = (WifiP2pManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
    }


    WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
            if(!peerList.getDeviceList().equals(peers)) {
                peers.clear();
                peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

                deviceNameArray = new String[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                deviceArray = new WifiP2pDevice[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                int index = 0;

                for(WifiP2pDevice device : peerList.getDeviceList()) {
                    deviceNameArray[index] = device.deviceName;
                    deviceArray[index] = device;
                    index++;
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceNameArray);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            if(peers.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Device Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

Below is my `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```java
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager mManager, WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel, MainActivity mActivity) {
        this.mManager = mManager;
        this.mChannel = mChannel;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        System.out.println("The following action was received: " + action);

        if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);

            //if wifi is enabled
            if(state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            if(mManager != null) {
                mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, mActivity.peerListListener);
            }
        } else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //do something
        } else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the print statements that show that the `onReceive()` method in the `BroadcastReceiver` class is being invoked continuously:

```
02/28 09:36:59: Launching 'app' on <default>.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.wifi_p2p/com.example.wifi_p2p.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.wifi_p2p/com.example.wifi_p2p.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 16127 on device 'emulator-5556'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:33): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=9369 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.example.wifi_p2p
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/xample.wifi_p2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd37d1f00, tid 16180
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xea07f040: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea07f040: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee4ecf0)
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd37d37b0, tid 16180
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ffff4000 size 0x2000
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea07f040: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee4ecf0)
Connected to process 13138 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
[emulator-5554]: W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:86): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7396 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c137,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.example.wifi_p2p
[emulator-5554]: D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
[emulator-5554]: W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
[emulator-5554]: D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
[emulator-5554]: D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
[emulator-5554]: D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
[emulator-5554]: W/xample.wifi_p2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
[emulator-5554]: W/xample.wifi_p2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
[emulator-5554]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5554]: D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd782df00, tid 13184
[emulator-5554]: D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
[emulator-5554]: D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe2e03f80: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
[emulator-5554]: D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2e03f80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xee1c0c10)
[emulator-5554]: W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
[emulator-5554]: D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
[emulator-5554]: D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd782f7b0, tid 13184
[emulator-5554]: D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
[emulator-5554]: D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff96f000 size 0x2000
[emulator-5554]: D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2e03f80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xee1c0c10)
[emulator-5556]: I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=2314ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=1156460386919, Vsync=1156560386915, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=1156560672300, AnimationStart=1156560763000, PerformTraversalsStart=1156560832900, DrawStart=1156910561000, SyncQueued=1156920522900, SyncStart=1156926542500, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1156926733800, SwapBuffers=1158606730000, FrameCompleted=1158780416000, DequeueBufferDuration=115000, QueueBufferDuration=365000, 
[emulator-5556]: I/Choreographer: Skipped 138 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[emulator-5556]: I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=2325ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=1156569082715, Vsync=1158869082623, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=1158875171400, AnimationStart=1158875274100, PerformTraversalsStart=1158875980300, DrawStart=1158878784600, SyncQueued=1158880673900, SyncStart=1158881629700, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1158881748500, SwapBuffers=1158892314200, FrameCompleted=1158895324000, DequeueBufferDuration=384000, QueueBufferDuration=339000, 
[emulator-5556]: D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea07f040: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee4ecf0)
[emulator-5556]: I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=2371ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=1156569082715, Vsync=1158869082623, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=1158875171400, AnimationStart=1158875274100, PerformTraversalsStart=1158875980300, DrawStart=1158929883300, SyncQueued=1158930916600, SyncStart=1158932402600, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1158932520500, SwapBuffers=1158933620300, FrameCompleted=1158942419300, DequeueBufferDuration=1796000, QueueBufferDuration=5476000, 
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/chatty: uid=10133(com.example.wifi_p2p) identical 2 lines
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/chatty: uid=10133(com.example.wifi_p2p) identical 2 lines
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/chatty: uid=10133(com.example.wifi_p2p) identical 1 line
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/chatty: uid=10133(com.example.wifi_p2p) identical 2 lines
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5554]: I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1680ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=8115584185014, Vsync=8115634185012, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=8115635788300, AnimationStart=8115635879400, PerformTraversalsStart=8115635951400, DrawStart=8115757362400, SyncQueued=8115765324900, SyncStart=8115772996200, IssueDrawCommandsStart=8115775766400, SwapBuffers=8117035456600, FrameCompleted=8117272014500, DequeueBufferDuration=63000, QueueBufferDuration=577000, 
[emulator-5556]: I/chatty: uid=10133(com.example.wifi_p2p) identical 2 lines
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
[emulator-5556]: I/chatty: uid=10133(com.example.wifi_p2p) identical 5 lines
[emulator-5556]: I/System.out: The following action was received: android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
```

Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the app on an emulator then I think this is an issue with the emulator because I had the same issue, But on device it works fine, On emulator keep the app open and then turn on airplane mode and then turn it off again then the condition will stay same and if the wifi is turned off then the condition will trigger again, But unfortunately when you restart the app the issue starts again, I was not able to find a solution to fix this on emulator, The workaround would be to run the app on an device